# Python socket server send message to another server in initialize

Tags: python, sockets, connection, sendmessage, asyncore

I want to run a server which accepts connections from a few clients and also want it to **send** a message to a specific **another** server -which listen 1234 port- in **init** time.

```
self.connect(('localhost', 1234))
self.buffer = 'connect'
```

I put it in init method. And
 made up that kind of code which is below.

```
class EchoHandler(asyncore.dispatcher_with_send):
def handle_read(self):
    data = self.recv(8192)
    if data:
        print data
        self.send(data + " echo")

class EchoServer(asyncore.dispatcher):
def __init__(self, host, port):
    asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self)
    self.create_socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    self.set_reuse_addr()
    self.bind((host, port))
    self.listen(5)
    self.connect(('localhost', 1234))
    self.buffer = 'connect'

def handle_accept(self):
    pair = self.accept()
    if pair is not None:
        sock, addr = pair
        print 'Incoming connection from %s' % repr(addr)
        handler = EchoHandler(sock)

def handle_write(self):
    sent = self.send(self.buffer)
    self.buffer = self.buffer[sent:]


server = EchoServer('localhost', 0)
asyncore.loop()
```

I need your help.. Looking forward your replies. Thank you..

Comment: And your problem is?

Comment: @claris code crashes